# Transaction didn't get roll back after a exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm running a `jpa`/`spring-mvc` project and in this code :

```
@Autowired
private GenericDao<AoModification, Integer> modif_dao;
....
@Transactional
public void save_ao( ... ) 
        throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    modif_dao.delete(ao.getAoModifications());

    modif_dao.create(new AoModification(
       new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(mf.date), mf.txt));
    ....
```

i got `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06-10-2011"` and its okey i forgot to put `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(mf.date)`.

the problem is that i even a exception is rised this line `modif_dao.delete(ao.getAoModifications());` has been persist in the database and the transaction didn't get rollback and i lost all my `AoModifications`.

So where is the problem !!!

is the `@Repository` annotation are creating automatically methods with `@Transactional` ?

hibernate.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

dao.GenericDaoJpaImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class GenericDaoJpaImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> 
                                            implements GenericDao<T, PK> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    ....

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        this.entityManager.remove(this.entityManager.contains(t) ? t : this.entityManager.merge(t));
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Set<T> ts) {
        for( T t : ts){
            delete(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not rollback because java.text.ParseException is inherited from java.lang.Exception, bit not from java.lang.RuntimeException. By default method with @Transactional annotation is rolled back when RuntimeException occured.

You can either catch ParseException (or Exception) and re-throw RuntimeException, for example:

```
@Transactional
public void save_ao( ... ) {

    try {
        modif_dao.delete(ao.getAoModifications());

        modif_dao.create(new AoModification(
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(mf.date), mf.txt));
        ....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error when saving ao...", e);

    }
```

Or you can modify @Transactional annotation to rollback for Exception with rollbackFor option:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Comment: thanks man i understand now ;) can you just put a example to how catch ParseException (or Exception) and re-throw RuntimeException so your answer will be perfect.

Comment: I added an example, so now should be pretty clear what I mean.

Comment: thanks and i choose to use `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)`